# How to fill a Chart in .NET Chart Helper dynamically

Tags: c#, asp.net, charts

I tried to fill a Doughnut Chart in ASP.Net with the Chart Helper Class. I have a collection of projects, these projects contain a few modules. I pass one project each time to the method which creates the Chart.

A foreach loops then through every module the project contains. For each module I want to display one Part in the Chart. For example the current project Contains 3 Module, the Dooughnut should display three parts based on its y Value. The next project contains 5 modules, so the chart should be build with 5 parts and its y Value.

I tried this:

```
var chart = new Chart(width: 300, height: 220).AddTitle("Test");

if (project!= null)
{
    foreach (var item in project.module)
    {
        chart.AddSeries(chartType: "Doughnut",
            xValue: new[] { item.TXT_Name },
            yValues: new[] { item.NUM_Hours });
    }
}
return chart.Write("png");
```

But then the Chart has just one part, because in every foreach the current module overrides the Series in the Chart.

Is there any way to build the Chart dynamically, based on the amount of modules in the project.

Thx for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just create two IEnumerables of your xValues and yValues and then add it to the Series

```
var chart = new Chart(width: 300, height: 220).AddTitle("Test");

var xValues = new List<String>();
var yValues = new List<int>();
foreach (var item in project.module)
{
    xValues.Add(item.TXT_Name);
    yValues.Add(item.NUM_Hours);
}

chart.AddSeries(chartType: "Doughnut",
        xValue: xValues,
        yValues: yValues);

return chart.Write("png");
```

I tried it with a List here